# How do check if a user exists just with their user ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a command called check that will check if a user is in the discord. The only parameter I'm going to have is a user ID, so I want to check if the user ID's in the discord. I tried figuring out this problem, but I've come to no conclusion. All help is appreciated!

Command Example: -check [random ID]

Comment: `I tried` - any code?

Comment: Nvm, I just found out that discord.js-commando is giving me the first letter instead of the entire argument. How can I fix this?

Comment: Nvm, I had to split the msg manually instead of using discord.js-commando.

Comment: The reason you're seeing the downvotes, is because you asked a question without giving much context, and then answered it yourself via comments and your own published answer - which also provided zero context of substantive value. 
Try to remember that these pages are not just for your benefit, but for the benefit of others as well. Adding more to your answer and question might help make sense of this for someone else who has the same question.

Answer (score -3):

I just had to manually split the message instead of using commando's arguments.

Comment: What message? Split it how? Show the code. This answer is totally unhelpful.